# Javascript setting object with variable

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to set up an object using a variable. Here's what I have:

```
var sortby = 'post_date';
var sort = { sortby : 'asc' };
```

but when I `console.log(sort)` I get `Object {sortby: "asc"}`

How can I set the key of this object to the value of a variable?

Comment: you can use `sort[sortBy]='asc'`

Comment: this `{sortby : 'asc' };` interpreted as this `{'sortby' : 'asc' }`. So use `sort[sortby]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to ES6 (the newest JavaScript standard), you could only do the following:

```
var sortby = 'post_date';
var sort = {};

sort[sortby] = 'asc';
```

However, if you made sure that you can use ES6 features for what you're doing, this is also possible:

```
var sortby = 'post_date';

var sort = {
  [sortby]: 'asc
};
```

See this pages for more information on ES6 features: https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features

Answer (score 2):

Object literals can't have dynamic property names, but property setter syntax works:

```
var sortby = 'post_date';
var sort = { };
sort[sortby] = 'asc';
```